# passport.initialize is not a function

Tags: express, passport.js

when I try to run the code, it gives an error of "passport.initialize is not a function."
can some-one help me?
here is the code: -

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('express-session');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const app = express();


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());// the problem arises here//
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 1):

You import `passport` as default from `express-session` package, you probably want to `import passport from 'passport'`